# Authors print customization in biblatex, package Biblatex-GOST

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use gost-numeric style in xelatex-biblatex-biber. I need changes concerning authors at least in @book and @article types but also it wil be good to see them in all types. 
When authors are 4 or more it is all ok.
When authors are 1 or 2 or 3 it is needed that first author (and only first) was printed before title (without [et al.]).
Also when authors are 1 or 2 or 3: after title it must be symbol / with ordinary space before and after. And after  that all authors must be printed including first one also.
Please help me if possible
How it is now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric, 
sorting=none,     
language=auto, 
babel=other 
]{biblatex}
\NewBibliographyString{langjapanese}    
\NewBibliographyString{fromjapanese}    
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{comm.bib}
@book{forrest_2_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {2 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_3_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {3 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q. and Mongo, A.R.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_4_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {4 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q. and Mongo, A.R. and Grag, S.U.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_1_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {1 author},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{comm.bib} 
\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: moewe (who amazingly caught it without reading Russian) has already answered. I'd just add that this is an experimental feature and could fail somehow (for example with sorting). Please also read §2 of the documentation, perhaps this is not what you (or your editor) really want.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want correctly, you only need

```
\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
```

The behaviour you seek has already been implemented in `biblatex-gost`, but is only enabled with

```
\printbibliography[env=gostbibliography]
```

With `\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}` we can keep the standard bibliography environment.

Unfortunately, I don't speak Russian, but the [`biblatex-gost` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-gost/doc/biblatex-gost.pdf) seems to have a word about this in §5.5. on p. 21.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}   
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{forrest_2_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {2 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_3_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {3 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q. and Mongo, A.R.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_4_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {4 authors},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T. and Ivvel, A.Q. and Mongo, A.R. and Grag, S.U.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
@book{forrest_1_2012,
    location = {London},
    title = {1 author},
    pagetotal = {100},
    publisher = {Publishing House},
    author = {Forrest, T.},
    date = {2012},
    hyphenation={english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 


\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}

\begin{document} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]